# Why does DisplayMemberPath does not work when put in Style for a WPF ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

Unless I add DisplayMemberPath on the combobox it does not work. I think it should take it from Style?

I have the comboBox initially disabled. I see it can work when I open another tab with same DataTemplate. Once it works on one instance, it imdly starts working on all. Is is anything to do with tabs?

```
 <Style x:Key="CollectionList" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Name"/>
 </Style>


 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
   Style="{StaticResource CollectionList}" 
   SelectedItem="{Binding Model.SelectedItem}" />
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? I tried your code without DisplayMemberPath in element node and it works fine for WPF 3.5 and 4.0, displaying item's name instead of ToString.

Comment: does not work - it display class name.

Comment: Well, I have only one explanation. Your item names contains value equal to class name.

Comment: not true as it does work when I explicitly set it on ComboBox. I understand its weird and am hoping if I can find someone who has workaround.

Comment: Let's compare our environments. I tested with .Net Framework 3.5 and 4.0. Do you use another version or maybe it's not a complete example? Is there any triggers in your style?

Comment: I tried this, does not work for me either.

Comment: I just tried it and it works fine for me. I'm using WPF 4.0 and VS 2010 Ultimate, without the most recent service pack. The Style is defined in Window.Resources and the ComboBox in the main content of the Window.

Comment: I am using WPF 4.0 and VS 2010 SP1 Prof. I have Style in a ResourceDictionary and ComboBox in DataTemplate.

Comment: @Rohit Can you verify that the ComboBox can read the ResourceDictionary? Do something that is easy to notice and that you know works, such a Background color.

Comment: @Rachel Background works. I have something new to add. see my post.

Comment: @Rohit Hrrm it is something to do with the TabControl. I wrapped the test I had in a TabControl and it loads fine for the 1st tab, but not the 2nd and 3rd. The DropDown of items is fine but the SelectedItem shows the class name.

Comment: @Rohit Does it work when you change the StaticResource to a DynamicResource? It does for me.

Comment: @Rachel! you rock! Please file an answer I can select.

Comment: @Rohit Glad that worked! Posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Style="{StaticResource CollectionList}"` to a `DynamicResource`

I am guessing it has something to do with the StaticResource getting loaded once, and the TabControl items getting loaded as needed